# How to make getJSON to update correctly an element after page loaded in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile, getjson

I'm trying to get a getJSON result to update an HTML element on page load, within a jquery mobile loaded website.

Now, I've read I should not rely on ready(), but bind to pageInit. So I tried, but it just won't work. I've tried many other events that could be logical to try within the API event documentation, without any success.

The closest I come to success is after the page is loaded, via ajax, if I refresh the page manually (with the browser's refresh button), getJSON does update the corresponding HTML element. And you guess, it's not what I want to achieve. Here is what the code looks like now, and where it is placed...

```html
<div data-role="page">
<script>
    $( '#pageContainer' ).live( 'pageinit',function(event){
    //an alert() here does fire right before the page is shown in the browser
    //here is the getJSON code.
    });    
</script>
```

Now, I need help to try to figure how to make it work. I only want an element X in the page to update with the text returned from a jSON when the page appears in the browser! Like a normal ready() function would have done !

(Maybe it is relevant to specify I'm running RC2 ?)

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use JSONP here, have you tried setting a setTimeout()? You have to trigger a callback after the json object is loaded so timing is essential.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I can use getJSON, because on browser refresh, it does work ! I just can't get it to work when jQuery mobile does it's trick to load a page in the DOM. jQuery mobile do tell that we should use pageinit event... (... or did you meant to do a setTimeout "before" the JSON so it waits until everything is finished?)

Comment: Hm, ok. Tried using the callback function of getJSON()?

Comment: You wouldn't believe it, but still haven't been able to try it. Seems like priorities changed at work, and I still haven't touched that project back yet ! (Just so you know, I haven't forgotten you! As soon as I try it, I'll be back with the followups !)